# How do I loop through a received array in PHP and query the database to return a new array?

Tags: php, database, for-loop

I have this code in php:

```
<?php

include_once("JSON.php");
$json = new Services_JSON();

//1. PROCESS RECEIVED ARRAY

$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$http_raw_post_data = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $http_raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);

//just decode to see what kind of object it is
$post_data = json_decode($http_raw_post_data,true);

if (is_array($post_data))
    $response = array("status" => "ok", "code" => 0, "original request" => $post_data);
else
    $response = array("status" => "error", "code" => -1, "original_request" => $post_data);


//CALL DB QUERY

$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die("Could not select database");


//CREATE FINAL ARRAY TO RETURN
$arrayToReturn = array();


//----------------------THIS FAILS, POSSIBLY DUE TO WHEN IT RETURNS

foreach ($post_data as $value) 
{
  //CREATE QUERY
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, SUM(points) AS PUNTOS FROM tags WHERE username='$value' GROUP BY username");

  echo "executing query...";

  //EXECUTE QUERY & ADD EACH USER/POINTS DICTIONARY TO $resultado ARRAY
  $resultado = array();
  while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
  {
    $resultado[] = $obj;
  }

  //STORE RESULTS IN NEW OBJECT TO RETURN
  $arrayToReturn[] = $resultado;

}

?>
```

I just edited the my original question and now I get my array...the response string logged by my iOS app, which is from the server response, is:

executing query...Array
executing query...Array
[[{"username":"xcodeSim","PUNTOS":"5"}],[{"username":"dannyrodri","PUNTOS":"5"}]]

Not sure where the word Array is coming from but I am getting an array with two arrays in it. I guess I just have to tweak it to make it into an array with just 2 dictionaries in it.  How do I encode this back to my iOS app?

Comment: what is your expected result and what result do you get

Comment: Shouldn't the query use `$value`, not `$_POST['userNa']`?

Comment: And when you interpolate an array reference in a string, you have to leave out the quotes. You should be getting a syntax error, aren't you?

Comment: That code that creates the `$response` and then creates and echoes `$processed` is probably not valid here. That is used in the sample that you grabbed this code from, but probably not relevant here. The creation of the response should probably be a product of the success or failure of your SQL commands, not just whether the request was a properly formatted JSON request.

Comment: I'd also suggest using `mysql_real_escape_string` in your SQL to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks. And as Barmar points out, you presumably should be using `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

the query in `$result`  will fail because of the quotes try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, SUM(points) AS PUNTOS FROM tags WHERE username='".$_POST["userNa"]."' GROUP BY username");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array_to_return = array();
if ($post_data) {
  $usernames = implode(',', array_map(function($u) {
    return "'" + mysql_real_escape_string($u) + "'";
  }));
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, SUM(points) AS PUNTOS FROM tags WHERE username IN ($usernames) GROUP BY username") or die (mysql_error());
  while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    array_to_return[] = $obj;
  }
}
echo json_encode($array_to_return);
```