# iOS pass NSData in request to codeIgniter

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter and am trying to build basic registration web service in it. I want to access this web service from iOS. I am passing `NSData` from iOS end to the webservice in codeIgniter.

Now how do I parse this NSData on php(codeIgniter) end?

Following is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:DEFAULT_TIMEOUT];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


        NSData *jsonData =[self dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:object];
        NSData *postData;
        NSString *postLength;
        if (object == nil) {
            NSString *PostParamters= parameters;
            postData = [PostParamters dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        }
        else {
            // goes here
            postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


            [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
        }   

    -(NSData *) dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:(id)obj
{
    NSArray *aVoidArray =@[@"NSDate"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([obj class], &count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
        if (![aVoidArray containsObject: key] )
        {
            if ([obj valueForKey:key]!=nil)
            {

                [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj valueForKey:key]] forKey:key];
            }
        }
    }
    //    TRC_DBG(@"Dict %@",dict);
    free(properties);
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict] options:0 error:&jsonError];
    if (jsonError!=nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return jsonData;
}
```

Code Igniter side:

```
function register_post() {
    $user = new User();

    //$po_ = $this->post();
    $po_=file_get_contents("php://input");
   // print_r($po_);die;
    $fillable = array("username", "first_name", "last_name", "gender", "dob", "profile_picture", "password", 
    "email", "facebook_id", "twitter_id", "google_id", "device_type", "device_identifier", "device_token", "allow_pushnotification",
    "allow_photo_library", "from");
    foreach ($po_ as $key => $value) { // i get error here
        if (in_array($key, $fillable))
        {
            $user->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    if (!$user->save()) {
        return $this->response(array("success" => false, "errors" => $user->error->all));
    } else {
        return $this->response(array(
                    "success" => true,
                    "message" => "User Register successfully",
                    "user" => $user->to_array(array("id", "email", "username"))
        ));
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
    <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()</p>
<p>Filename: api/users.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 25</p>
```

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

**EDIT**
Response for : `$po_=file_get_contents("php://input");
        print_r($po_);die;`

```
{
"allow_pic" :0,
"allow_push" : 0,
"device_token" : "",
"device_type" : iOS,     **Edited again**
"dob" : "1992-12-31",
"email" : "ertert@asd.asd",
"first_name" : "",
"from" : 0,
"gender" : 0,
"is_active" : 0,
"last_name" : "",
"password" : "asdasd",
"total_fav" : 0,
"total_space" : 0,
"used_space" : 0,
"utype" : 1
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what a var_dump($_REQUEST) at the begining of your function gives you ?

Comment: @AdrienXL - Please see the edited question. It includes the response. $_REQUEST gives empty response hence I have shown the other one.

Comment: So you get a json. Try : `$po_ = json_decode($po_,true);`

Comment: @AdrienXL- Did it. It isn't working. Please see the edited code again.

Comment: actually from iOS side I am passing NSData and it automatically deals with the quotes. So some of the values and keys are without quotes and hence it's not json.

Comment: You are right, not a valid json. I'm doing some research. Have you seen this btw : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910578/objective-c-json-php-array

Comment: No I haven't. Thanks, am going through the post right now. I don't think I need to change anything on iOS end right? It has to be changed on php side, yeah?

Comment: Actually, I don't know, never played with iOS stuff :(

Comment: oh alright :) let me know if you find anything on how this can be solved on php side then.

Comment: After some tests, it's seems clear that the iOS part is the troublemaker. I can build an array from what you get with some explode() and substr() but this is definitely not the clean way to do that.

Comment: @AdrienXL - I got it working with json_decode($po_) in foreach :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for letting me know. Idk why I absolutely wanted that second parameter :(